# Problem sorting an array with HeapSort method in c++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a program in visual studio with c++ and winapi. In the program I have to register data of people and vaccines to create vaccination cards and all the information is stored in the doubly linked list called CARNET.

One of the functions that the program must have is that in a window it organizes the names of the people in a listbox either by QuickSort or HeapSort method, for each method I have a button.

In each button what is done is to clean the listbox, then the size of the list is calculated, an array is created where the information of the list is copied, the arrangement is sent to order by one of the two methods and finally the arrangement is printed in the listbox.
In the case of the QuickSort method, the arrangement is ordered by the name of the person, in the HeapSort it is ordered by the identification number (id).

The QuickSort method is ready, the problem is with the HeapSort method, when calling this method instead of ordering the information by HeapSort I do it by QuickSort but so far I can not know why. I already checked that both buttons had their respective id and were called by it.
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance :)

```
struct CARDS {

    //Vaccine Data
    wchar_t no_dose[20]{};
    wchar_t price[20]{};
    wchar_t brand[40]{};

    //Person's data
    wchar_t name[60]{};
    wchar_t surname[30]{};
    wchar_t marital_status[40]{};
    wchar_t sex[40]{};
    wchar_t date_birth[40]{};
    wchar_t city[30];
    wchar_t state[30];
    wchar_t tel[20]{};
    

    //Dosage data
    SYSTEMTIME date_dosage{};
    wchar_t no_dosage[10]{};
    wchar_t place_vacc[100]{};
    
    //CARD id
    int id{};

    CARDS* next{};
    CARDS* prev{};
};

CARDS* Lstart = NULL; //Indicates the head of the list
CARDS* Lend = NULL; //Indicates the end of the list
//-----------------------------------------------------
//Quicksort
void change(CARDS* a, CARDS* b) {
    
    //Vaccine Data
    swap(a->no_dose, b->no_dose);
    swap(a->price, b->price);
    swap(a->brand, b->brand);
    
    //Person's data
    swap(a->name, b->name);
    swap(a->surname, b->surname);
    swap(a->marital_status, b->marital_status);
    swap(a->sex, b->sex);
    swap(a->date_birth, b->date_birth);
    swap(a->city, b->city);
    swap(a->state, b->state);
    swap(a->tel, b->tel);
    

    //Dosage data
    swap(a->date_dosage, b->date_dosage);
    swap(a->no_dose, b->no_dose);
    swap(a->place_vacc, b->place_vacc);
    
    //CARD id
    swap(a->id, b->id);
}

int partition(CARDS* arr, int start, int end) {
    wstring pivot = arr[end].name;
    int i = start - 1;

    for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
        if (arr[j].name<=pivot) {
            i++;
            change(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }

    change(&arr[i + 1], &arr[end]);
    return i + 1;
}

void quicksort(CARDS* arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int index_pivot = partition(arr, start, end);
        quicksort(arr, start, index_pivot - 1);
        quicksort(arr, index_pivot + 1, end);
    }
}


//HeapSort
void heapify(CARDS* arr, int n, int i)
{
    int largest = i; 
    int l = 2 * i + 1; 
    int r = 2 * i + 2; 

    
    if (l<n && arr[l].id>arr[largest].id)
        largest = l;

    
    if (r<n && arr[r].id > arr[largest].id)
        largest = r;


    if (largest != i) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[largest]);
        
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

void heapSort(CARDS* arr, int n)
{
    
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i);

    
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);
        
        
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK Quicksort_call(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    int select = NULL;
    wchar_t fe[50]{};
    wchar_t idString;
    int id;
    wstring ageString;
    switch (message) {

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        long opc = LOWORD(wParam);
        BAR_MENU(window, opc);
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        
        case IDC_BUTTON1: {
            SendDlgItemMessage(window, IDC_LIST2, LB_RESETCONTENT, NULL, 0);

            int size = 0;
            for (CARDS* aux = Lstart; aux != nullptr; aux = aux->next) {
                size++;
            }

            CARDS* arr = new CARDS[size];
            int index = 0;
            for (CARDS* aux = Lstart; aux != nullptr; aux = aux->next) {
                arr[index] = *aux;
                index++;
            }
            quicksort(arr, 0, size - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                wchar_t full_name[150] = L"";
                wchar_t idStr[20];
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr[i].name);
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr[i].surname);
                swprintf(idStr, sizeof(idStr) / sizeof(wchar_t), L"%d", arr[i].id);
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), idStr);



                SendDlgItemMessage(window, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)full_name);
            }
            delete[]arr;
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON2: {
            SendDlgItemMessage(window, IDC_LIST2, LB_RESETCONTENT, NULL, 0);

            int size2 = 0;
            for (CARDS* aux = Lstart; aux != nullptr; aux = aux->next) {
                size2++;
            }

            CARDS* arr2 = new CARDS[size2];
            int index = 0;
            for (CARDS* aux = Lstart; aux != nullptr; aux = aux->next) {
                arr2[index] = *aux;
                index++;
            }

            
            
            heapSort(arr2, size2);
            for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {

                wchar_t full_name[150] = L"";
                wchar_t idStr[20];
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr[i].name);
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr[i].surname);
                swprintf(idStr, sizeof(idStr) / sizeof(wchar_t), L"%d", arr[i].id);
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(full_name, sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(wchar_t), idStr);

                SendDlgItemMessage(window, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)full_name);
            }



            delete[] arr2;
            break;
        }
}

        break;
    }
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        
        

        break;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Run the code in the debugger and put a breakpoint on `switch (LOWORD(wParam))` then click the button and step through to see what happens.

Comment: What are you doing? You're doing way too much work and your code is more "C" then "C++"

Comment: @RetiredNinja I just did it, when selecting the HeapSort button if you enter the IDC_BUTTON2 option and call the heapSort function, if the array is sent and the size is correct but the result it gives me is the same as the QuickSort method. It does not give me the result that should give the HeapSort

Comment: Are you sure your data set is such that sorting by ID actually gives you different results to sorting by name?

Comment: They should be different. In my program the IDs are assigned consecutively and in increment (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) as they are created. So when calling HeapShort I should leave the arrangement as it was, but instead it orders me depending on the name as in the QuickShort method. I modified the HeapShort function a little and implemented it in a simple code where you have to sort an array of type int with several random numbers, in this case the result was as expected, I order the array correctly.

Comment: Looks like you sort arr2, but then display the first (quicksorted) arr.

Comment: Another question is how you could compile that. Guess you either have a global arr somewhere, or just miscopied your example.

Comment: @MikeTyukanov spotted it. `arr2` is sorted but `arr` is used to populate the list. Looks like a copy/paste error in that for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Not a real answer,but more of an example of what your code could look like in current C++ :
Another tip : write functions like this in a seperate C++ static lib (without including ANY windows headers) first. Write some tests for that lib. And when that works start using the functions from your windows code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct card_t
{
    std::uint64_t no_dose;  // be typesafe number of doses is not a string
    double price;           // be typesafe a price is not a string (consider using some currency type)
    std::string brand;      // replace all your wchar_t with std::wstring
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point date_dosage{}; // use C++ time type
    std::size_t id;

    // never mix data with datastructures
    // so no next/prev. 
};

// no need to write change or swap function
// rely on copy assigment/copy construction for cards_t
// if needed you can use std::swap
// using pointers as much as you do is also not recommended.


//HeapSort
// CARDS* arr, int n -> std::vector<cards_t>&
// int i -> std::size_t i (integers can be negative which will 
// always be incorrect indices, use std::size_t for 
// datastructure sizes)
// variable naming, name variables according to WHAT they represent
// not HOW they are implemented
void heapify(std::vector<card_t>& cards, std::size_t i)
{
    std::size_t largest = i;
    std::size_t left = 2 * i + 1; // nothing wrong with writing 'left' 
    std::size_t right = 2 * i + 2;

    // add some extra '(' and ')' for readability
    // and to avoid typos causing bugs
    if ((left < cards.size()) && (cards[left].id > cards[largest].id))
    {
        largest = left;
    }

    if ((right < cards.size()) && (cards[right].id > cards[largest].id))
    {
        largest = right;
    }

    if (largest != i) 
    {
        // use C++ build in swap function
        // note this will be slow (even in your implementation)
        // since you are swapping full structs. Not pointers.
        std::swap(cards[i], cards[largest]);
        heapify(cards, largest);
    }
}

void heapSort(std::vector<card_t>& arr)
{
    if (arr.size() < 2ul) return; // never trust input, too small array cannot be sorted

    for (std::size_t i = arr.size() / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        heapify(arr, i);
    }

    for (std::size_t i = arr.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) 
    {
        std::swap(arr[0], arr[i]);
        heapify(arr, 0);
    }
}

auto load_cards()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals; // for ""s std::string creation

    auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // note a std::vector of std::unique_ptr<card_t> would be 
    // more efficient since sorting would then only have to swap
    // pointers to card_t not the whole card_t structure
    // but thats another refactor excercise for you

    std::vector<card_t> cards
    {
        { 1, 1.0, "brand1"s, time, 1ul}, // initialize structs members
        { 4, 4.0, "brand4"s, time, 4ul},
        { 3, 3.0, "brand3"s, time, 3ul},
        { 5, 5.0, "brand2"s, time, 5ul},
    };

    return cards;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<card_t>& cards)
{
    for (const auto& card : cards)
    {
        os << card.id << ":" << card.brand << "\n";
    }

    return os;
}

bool compare_cards_by_id(const card_t& lhs, const card_t& rhs)
{
    return lhs.id < rhs.id;
}


int main()
{
    // Note your heap algorithm does not terminate,
    // so still buggy. Consider using :
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap
    std::cout << "heap sort\n";
    auto cards = load_cards();
    heapSort(cards);
    std::cout << cards << "\n";

    // quicksort, by passing a predicate it is so
    // easy to sort by different 
    std::cout << "quick sort\n";
    cards = load_cards();
    std::sort(cards.begin(), cards.end(), compare_cards_by_id);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't have an answer, don't hit the *"Post Your Answer"* button.